# How to assign hub name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to set the hub name of the class for the SignalR. Here is the class which inherits the Hub class:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already defining the name when you declare ChatHub:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
```

{

}

If you want a different name for your Hub:

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
```

{

}

Comment: But I want to assign some other name to the hub name.